# Is it possible to run a single method with and without parameter in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate the tax of total amount during `onchange` of quantity or price values.

Here is what I did:

```
function sum() {
    var result1 = document.getElementById('result1').value; 
    var result2 = document.getElementById('result2').value; 
    var result3 = document.getElementById('result3').value; 
    var result4 = document.getElementById('result4').value; 
    var result5 = document.getElementById('result5').value; 
    var result6 = document.getElementById('result6').value; 

    var myResult = Number(result1) + Number(result2) + Number(result3) + Number(result4) + Number(result5) + Number(result6);
    tax(myResult);
    document.getElementById('sumvalue').value = myResult;
}
```

Here result1,2,3.. are sub total of items. Total amount is passed to the tax calculation.

```
function tax(tot) {
    var taxval = document.getElementById('tax_val').value;
    amt = (tot * taxval)/100 ;
    document.getElementById('tax_amt').value = amt;
}
```

`tax_amt` is the Tax Amount final value. My requirement is: when I change the tax value, I need to run this same method.

Below element is the tax percentage holder. Whenever I change the value it must be frequently change the `tax_total`.

```
<input id="tax_val" type="number" value="15" oninput="tax(this_element_value)" >
```

Comment: so call sum when the value changes.... Or have the tax method read the textbox value and not pass it in....

Comment: Superb. It Worked... Thanks for your help.@epascarello. How dump I am :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I understand that you want realtime update of tax, when input is changed.

I would do something like this:

```
<input id="tax_val" type="number" value="15" oninput="onInputChanged(this)" >
function onInputChanged(elem) {
    tax(elem.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign a class to all the elements variables (result1, result2, result3...) then add a event to this class like this:

```
$(".result").change(function () {

   sum();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        <input class="input-class" />

        <input class="input-class" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.input-class').on('change', function () {
           /// here you need find input and there value then you can sum of these value.
        });
    </script>
```

check this. I think it helps you.